# From a script, run a script on a remote server and get its output

Tags: perl, ssh

I am executing a Perl script. I have to SSH to a remote server and execute a python script. Below is the line of code that I am executing in the perl script. I know there are few options like backticks and system command  to execute a python script but I have the script in remote server and I cannot  use system or backticks command as it is not local machine. I want the output of the command that I am executing through SSH at runtime.

```
   my $ssh = new Net::SSH::Expect();
    $ssh->login_username($server_login);
    $ssh->server($server_name);
    $ssh->login();
    my $home_directory= $ssh->pwd;

my $command=qq(/home/feroz/MyScript.py $ARG0 $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3 1)
    print "\n-------- BEGIN SCRIPT OUTPUT ----------\n";
    $ssh->exec($command)){

    print "\n -------- END SCRIPT OUTPUT ----------";
```

Comment: `SSH::Expect` is not a module on CPAN. Is this a custom module or did you typo `Net::SSH::Expect` ?

Comment: Yes Net::SSH sorry for the typo

Comment: The documentation for `Net::SSH::Expect` does not mention a `login_username`, but it *does* state that the output of `$command` is returned from `->exec`. So have you tried simply `print $ssh->exec($command);` ?

Comment: I have tried it as well but did not succeed

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod) documentation.  You aren't using it right

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host     => 'host name', 
    user     => 'user name', 
    password => 'password', 
    raw_pty  => 1
);

my $greeting = $ssh->login();  # or $ssh->run_ssh(), if without password
print $greeting;

# Disable terminal translations and echo on the SSH server
$ssh->exec("stty raw -echo");

my $cmd = q( ... );

my $cmd_output = $ssh->exec($cmd);

print $cmd_output, "\n";
```

The `exec` method is one of the ways to get the command output. Some others are `read_line`, `peek`, `eat`, and there are yet other ways to interact with the command.

Please add checks to see whether the login worked first.

This can accomplish a lot and it involves complexities. PLease read the documentation.